# Google Sheets Query doesn't return all data

Tags: google-sheets-query

this is my first time posting and I am a beginner with Google Sheets. I am trying to use QUERY to return 3 columns of data with a condition that the number column is greater than 0. Here is what I entered into the formula bar:

=QUERY(AS293:AU302, "Select AS,AT,AU where (AU>0)", 0)

Here is the data set:

[image: data set]

For the sake of simplicity, this is only a portion of the total data. It doesn't matter - the query doesn't work whether the data is 12 rows or 112 rows.

This is the output:

[image: Output]

I've tried the query without the "where" condition, I've tried changing the numbers to text format, and nothing changes. I've even copied the query from another worksheet where it is working (just changing the cell references).

Any help is appreciated! Seems like this would be pretty straightforward, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Make sure your entire column AU is formatted as NUMBER.  Looks like text right now (left-aligned).  `=QUERY(AS293:AU302, "where AU>0", 0)` should work.